# Why I do not get the registration mail from freenode in gmail

Tags: gmail, irc, freenode

I try to register my nickname on freenode with this command:

```
/msg Nickserv REGISTER secretpassword nickname@gmail.com
```

I do get a confirmation that a email was sent to `nickname@gmail.com` but there isn't an email in my inbox also not in SPAM folder.

The output of `/msg Nickserv Info` told me that my nickname registration is not completed. Is there any limitation on freenode IRC while using gmail or can I change the email address for the registration process?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Freenode staff in `#freenode`?

Comment: Thx for the hint, I join the channel and ask the same question as here.

Comment: @grawity in the #freenode channel I get the hint to drop the registration an register with a diffrent Address than my gmail address, than I change with /msg Nickserv SET EMAIL nickname@gmail.com the email address and that works.

Comment: @kockiren please post that as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a new query window by typing this command in freenode commandline:

```
/query nickserv help
```

From this window try to run your verification code you got in your email.